# Dynamic Tabs on runtime in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

My app is a holiday search app. Once the user touch 'search' button it will do a web query and gather results from various providers such as BING, YAHOO, ETC... I want to show these results tabbed according to the provider. I want to use a table to show the list of results of one provider and a tabbar on the bottom of the screen to switch providers.
The number of providers is dynamic means it can ONLY be known once the web query is done. So number of tabs required/view controllers required is NOT known prior to the web request.

Any idea how to implement this ???. Since i'm bit new to IOS dev, I would be delighted if you can provide a detailed description. Thank you. Feel free to ask any question if you do not get my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add ViewControllers to a tab bar and it will display a tab for that view controller - so you would have to put each result set into a view controller and add them to the tab bar.

be aware a tab bar can only display 5 tabs before it switches to 4 tabs and a more… controller.

A possibly better way would be to have a button that brings up a UIPickerView which has a list of the result sources. that way you can have as many result sources as you like!

Comment: Thanks I am trying the pickerview idea.